# Laravel starter kit

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I've downloaded laravel 4 starter kit, I already have composer but when I run `composer install` to install the starter kit I get this error:

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/Translation/zipball/v2.3.1" file
could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Comment: Run `composer update` and try again. If it still doesn't work run `composer diagnose` and paste the output.

Comment: Thanks it works fine now  i updated composer , removed starter kit folder and then installed it again and it's working now ! :)

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when there is issue in your network connectivity such as packet loss from your network to the destination host. Try reset your network connection and try again to download using the composer.